# Meaning of the word "from" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is from this [article](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/darwins-subterranean-world/201910/the-end-sex). Here it goes:

> While our brave new world has lots of amazing new opportunities and affordances for all of us, we need to always keep in mind that the modern world is deeply mismatched **from** ancestral human conditions in many important ways. (For more, see, Positive Evolutionary Psychology, by Geher & Wedberg.) And evolutionary mismatch often leads to problems.

Does it mean *because*?

Comment: No, it means "due to".

Comment: Uh, _because_ ~= _due to_.

Comment: @Lambie
 The phrase  "*deeply mismatched from ancestral human conditions* seems to mean "significantly different from ancestral human conditions". I don't see how this could be read as "because" or "due to"

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to understand this is to take a cynical view of the writing process.

The writer mechanistically removed synonyms from the work after completing it. Or got negative feedback about the wording.

So you can guess that what they originally wrote was something like

> The modern world is **different from** ancestral conditions. It’s deeply mismatched in many ways.

It can’t mean *because* actually.  The right hand side or second half is not an independent clause.

The ending—*in many important ways*—-is just a modifier.  This is also true of *ancestral human*.

Then we can drop the modifiers and it should still make sense.

Dropping them and substituting *because*, we get

> ... we need to always keep in mind that the modern world is deeply mismatched because conditions.

The illogical result shows the initially assumed meaning, *because*, is not valid.

Ultimately in the context of the article that sentence means we have to remember that today is **different from** the past.

Answer (score 1):

I read it as *mismatched from ancestral conditions* = *not matched to ancestral conditions*.

It is not an adjunct phrase giving purpose or comparison: it is a complement of *mismatched* saying what something fails to be matched to.

While *from* is not the most obvious preposition to use to express the complement of *mismatched*, this is not unique. The NOW corpus has 123 instances of *mismatched to* and 33 instances of *mismatched from*. (Some of the latter are a different construction, eg *mismatched from the beginning*, but many of them are just like the given example.)